# postgresql, deferred constraint not working as I expect

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling to understand the way DEFERRED constraints work in postgres (v13 if that matters).

I have the following schema and data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 (
  id int,
  CONSTRAINT unique_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 (
  id int,
  ref int,
  CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (ref) REFERENCES t1 (id) ON DELETE SET NULL DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t2 (id,ref) VALUES (1,1);
```

Then I execute the instructions below:

```
BEGIN;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

DELETE FROM t1;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
COMMIT;
```

Because constraints are deferred, I would expect the ON DELETE SET NULL to trigger at the end of the transaction and preserve the link from `t1` to `t2`. Yet it does not.

```
SELECT * FROM t2;
 id | ref 
----+-----
  1 |    
(1 row)
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEFERRABLE only means that the *check* if no row violates the constraint is postponed until the transaction is committed. It does **not** mean that the *effect* of the DML that you run, is postponed until the end of the transaction.

In your example at the end of the transaction no row in `t2` violates the foreign key constraint. So the COMMIT is successful.

Additionally: the `DELETE FROM t1` will set all `ref` columns to `NULL` in the table `t2` that contained the deleted IDs. If you then insert a new row into `t1`, how should Postgres know which of the (possibly millions) of `ref` columns that are NULL to reset to the initial value?